# Need help getting past 'reflect: NumField of non-struct type'

Tags: pointers, struct, go

I am trying to build a Query struct that will represent data to and from our Cassandra database.

The issue is, I am trying to take a Type as one of my fields in the struct so I can reconstruct it later. I feel like I am really close, but it is giving me some issues. I get a really nasty looking error trying to do this:

```
2015/11/17 15:42:22 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:57962: reflect: NumField of non-struct type
goroutine 34 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc820184000, 0x7f36d7459b00, 0xc820180008)
    /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:1287 +0xb5
reflect.(*rtype).NumField(0x790820, 0xc8200b9a60)
    /usr/lib/go/src/reflect/type.go:660 +0x7b
github.com/relops/cqlr.(*Binding).compile(0xc82004f6f0, 0x77ab60, 0xc8200b9a60, 0x16, 0xc820194140, 0x5, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/jared/dev/go-pp/src/github.com/relops/cqlr/cqlr.go:160 +0xf8
github.com/relops/cqlr.(*Binding).Scan(0xc82004f6f0, 0x77ab60, 0xc8200b9a60, 0x825280)
    /home/jared/dev/go-pp/src/github.com/relops/cqlr/cqlr.go:99 +0x199
main/cassandra/query.Query.RetryingQuery(0x9325e0, 0x19, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f36d74580a8, 0x87b120, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /home/jared/dev/go-pp/src/main/cassandra/query/query.go:39 +0x39e
main.ViewHosts(0x7f36d7459f88, 0xc8200e73f0, 0xc82018e000)
    /home/jared/dev/go-pp/src/main/handlers.go:86 +0x1f3
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x9a03b0, 0x7f36d7459f88, 0xc8200e73f0, 0xc82018e000)
    /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:1422 +0x3a
main/utils.Logger.func1(0x7f36d7459f88, 0xc8200e73f0, 0xc82018e000)
    /home/jared/dev/go-pp/src/main/utils/logger.go:32 +0x9c
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc820109200, 0x7f36d7459f88, 0xc8200e73f0, 0xc82018e000)
    /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:1422 +0x3a
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc82001aa00, 0x7f36d7459f88, 0xc8200e73f0, 0xc82018e000)
    /home/jared/dev/go-pp/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:100 +0x29e
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc82016b1a0, 0x7f36d7459f88, 0xc8200e73f0, 0xc82018e000)
    /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:1862 +0x19e
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc820184000)
    /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:1361 +0xbee
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:1910 +0x3f6
```

Here is the code

```
type Query struct {
    query       string
    values      interface{}
    attempts    int
    maxAttempts int
    structType  reflect.Type
}

func NewQuery(query string, t reflect.Type) (q Query) {
    q.query = query
    q.structType = t
    return
}

func (query Query) RetryingQuery() (results []interface{}) {
    var q *gocql.Query
    if query.values != nil {
        q = c.Session.Query(query.query, query.values)
    } else {
        q = c.Session.Query(query.query)
    }

    bindQuery := cqlr.BindQuery(q)

    value := reflect.New(query.structType).Pointer()
    for bindQuery.Scan(&value) {
        results = append(results, value)
    }
    return
}


// setting up and calling the query here (in another file)
var host cmodels.Host
query := query.NewQuery("SELECT * FROM server.host", reflect.TypeOf(host))
queryResults := query.RetryingQuery()
```

However, with slight modification of the code I get past the error but I am getting a weird result.

```
func (query Query) RetryingQuery() (results []interface{}) {
    var q *gocql.Query
    if query.values != nil {
        q = c.Session.Query(query.query, query.values)
    } else {
        q = c.Session.Query(query.query)
    }

    bindQuery := cqlr.BindQuery(q)
    value := reflect.New(query.structType)
    for bindQuery.Scan(&value) {
        results = append(results, value)
    }
    return
}
```

That code above gives me:

```
[{"flag":22},{"flag":22},{"flag":22},{"flag":22},{"flag":22},...]
```

Comment: Do you mean to have `for bindQuery.Scan(&value)` or `if bindQuery.Scan(&value)`? That's not what's causing your panic, just clarifying.

Comment: should be for, bindQuery is a slice and we want to go through each of them and append them to the list. That is where I am having problems though, getting value right

Comment: `bindQuery.Scan` appears to return a bool: https://godoc.org/github.com/relops/cqlr#Binding.Scan

Comment: I don't think I care about the bool, just wantto do the iterating over the `bindQuery`, Either way, see most recent edit.

Comment: Oh, I see, it will keep doing the Scan until it returns false.

Comment: Ah, that might be how it works. I haven't really looked too much at the internals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change from:

```
value := reflect.New(query.structType)
for bindQuery.Scan(&value) {
```

to:

```
value := reflect.New(query.structType).Interface()
for bindQuery.Scan(value) {
```

See [here](http://play.golang.org/p/1FIL0vzROZ) for a full working example (pasted below):

```
package main

import "reflect"

func Scan(d interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(d)
    i := reflect.Indirect(v)
    s := i.Type()
    println(s.NumField()) // will print out 0, if you change Host to have 1 field, it prints out 1
}

func query(t reflect.Type) {
    value := reflect.New(t).Interface()
    Scan(value)
}

type Host struct{}
// type Host struct{int} // comment above line, uncomment this one, and println above will print 1

func main() {
    var h Host
    query(reflect.TypeOf(h))
}
```

This emulates what your code, plus the clqr library, does (see https://github.com/relops/cqlr/blob/master/cqlr.go#L85-L99 and https://github.com/relops/cqlr/blob/master/cqlr.go#L154-L160).  You basically need `s := i.Type()` to be the `TypeOf` your `Host` struct, so if you work backwards from what the clqr code is doing, you can deduce what you need to pass in to the `Scan` call.  And given that the input you have is a `reflect.Type`, you can deduce how you can get from that `Type` to the correct kind of object to pass into `Scan`.